# Parse XML api using curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

i am trying to parse a xml data using the an api url which i have used in the following code. when i run this url directly in the browser it gives me a xml formatted data like below.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>B4DE627B9936548B</RequestId>
<HostId>LyB4mVbYLYF/a26Wn04sSuMlTwQjLozl11O9Ql2YbMwHgenXRUCd7WAn5QPRa6nj</HostId>
</Error>
```

but i want this xml in an array then i will itrate that array using foreach loop.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com  
/11111.mpg&mpaction=convert%20format=flv');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Your application name');

$query = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

echo $query;

?>
```

when i print the variable $query it gives me only the text of xml. i want this xml in an array. please help me

Answer (score 1):

CURL is not used for pasing data. You'll have to resort to some library for that. For your case, i recommend using [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML). Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($query);
var_dump($xml);
```

You can then access the various properties using standard array indexes:

```
echo $xml['Message']; // Yields "Access Denied"
```

Comment: @rajzana Just replace your `echo $query` with my code and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

To convert the XML into an array, as [alexn already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022438/parse-xml-api-using-curl/8022456#8022456), you can make use of [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) and cast it's return value to an array:

```
$array = (array) simplexml_load_string($query);
print_r($array);
```

That gives you:

```
Array
(
    [Code] => AccessDenied
    [Message] => Access Denied
    [RequestId] => B4DE627B9936548B
    [HostId] => LyB4mVbYLYF/a26Wn04sSuMlTwQjLozl11O9Ql2YbMwHgenXRUCd7WAn5QPRa6nj
)
```

Which might be exactly what you're looking for.